# Need to reduce execution time in python 3 code for large outputs

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a program that has the first input for the number of elements in the input array , the second input is the input array and the third input is the numbers to be counted in the list

```
num = int(input())
array = input()
lissst = array.split() 
lissst = [int(a) for a in lissst]
num_query = int(input())
i = num_query
while i > 0:
    queries = int(input())
    x = lissst.count(queries)
    if x > 0:
        print (x) 
    elif x == 0:
        print("NOT PRESENT")
    i = i - 1
```

Input format is as shown below:

6

1 1 1 2 2 0

6 
1

2

1

0

3

4

Output layout is as follows:

3

2

3

1

NOT PRESENT

NOT PRESENT

I need to reduce execution time for large inputs, any tips on how to do so for this particular problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slowness probably comes from here:

```
x = lissst.count(queries)
```

since `list.count` has to read the whole list each time.

You can speed it up by putting each number from the input array in a dictionary (number -> how often it appeared in the array). Below I use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which is just a convenient wrapper around dicts:

```
from collections import Counter

num = int(input())

array = input()
array = [int(a) for a in array.split()]
counter = Counter(array)

i = int(input())

while i > 0:
    query = int(input())
    x = counter[query]
    if x > 0:
        print (x) 
    else:
        print("NOT PRESENT")
    i -= 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It reduces the time but could you explain how this differs from the method i used and also if you have any other methods of reducing time complexity of such problems.

Comment: @MadalitsoPhiri You used `count()` method, which have time complexity `O(n)`, in cycle, so time complexity of counting is `O(i*n)`. In RafG's answer counter is used outside the cycle, and in cycle `counter[query]` is used, which have time compexity `O(1)`. So, time complexity of counting in this case is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

to answer on the query number faster, you can build a dictionary mapping of number -> count.

when receiving query number, use the dictionary mapping to return the result in O(1) amortized (instead of O(n) of the original naive solution)

**build the mapping** `O(n)`:

```
num2count = {}
for i in my_array:
    if not i in num2count:
        num2count[i] = 1
    else:
        num2count[i] += 1
```

**answer a query "how many times x in array"** `O(1)` on average

```
counts = num2count.get(x, 0)
```

**Your code updated**

```
num = int(input())
array = input()
lissst = array.split() 
lissst = [int(a) for a in lissst]

num2count = {}
for i in lissst:
    if not i in num2count:
        num2count[i] = 1
    else:
        num2count[i] += 1

num_query = int(input())
i = num_query
while i > 0:
    queries = int(input())
    x = num2count.get(queries, 0)
    if x > 0:
        print (x) 
    elif x == 0:
        print("NOT PRESENT")
    i = i - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the existing answers, you could try Pypy: https://pypy.org

“If you want your code to run faster, you should probably just use PyPy.” — Guido van Rossum (creator of Python)